# how to stop clash between jquery and protoype on this page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, magento

This page is a combination of magento and a wordpress theme. Unfortunately the jquery is causing the protoype not to work but I'm not to amazing at using developer tools to locate these kinds of problems. 
My understanding is that I need to run jquery in noConflict mode but I can't find where it is called from the wordpress theme.
Can anyone advise how I can locate this or solve the problem.
http://www.findcarpettiles.co.uk/wp/general-information/free-samples-measurement/
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is included and ran in noConflict mode automatically. I believe your problem is that you include two versions of jQuery (one from Magento and one from WP). If I were you, I would add the following to your functions.php to stop WP from including its version of jQuery.

```
add_filter( 'wp_default_scripts', 'change_default_jquery' );

function change_default_jquery( &$scripts){
    if(!is_admin()){
        $scripts->remove( 'jquery');
    }
}
```